# how do I replace all the links in a text using regex in as3?

Tags: regex, flash, actionscript-3, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I linkify text using ActionScript 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162932/how-do-i-linkify-text-using-actionscript-3)

I am using a regular expression to find links in a generic string and highlight that text(underline, a href, anything).

Here's what I have so far:

```
var linkRegEx:RegExp = new RegExp("(https?://)?(www\\.)?([a-zA-Z0-9_%]*)\\b\\.[a-z]{2,4}(\\.[a-z]{2})?((/[a-zA-Z0-9_%]*)+)?(\\.[a-z]*)?(:\\d{1,5})?","g");
var link:String = 'generic links: www.google.com http://www.yahoo.com  stackoverflow.com';
link = addLinks(linkRegEx,link);
textField.htmlText = link;//textField is a TextField I have on stage

function addLinks(pattern:RegExp,text:String):String{
    while((pattern.test(text))!=false){
        text=text.replace(pattern, "<u>link</u>");
    }
    return text;
}
```

I get all the text replaced with "link". I'd like to have the same text that was matching the expresion instead of "link". I tried

```
text=text.replace(pattern, "<u>"+linkRegEx.exec(text)[0]+"</u>");
```

but I ran into trouble. I don't think I fully understand how regex and the replace method work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I've read the documentation for the [replace()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/String.html#replace%28%29) method.

There are two key things:

1. You can use **$&** to get the matched substring. A lot of handy and weird looking symbols there.
2. **Use a second string** when replacing, otherwise you end up in an endless loops and tiny black wholes keep spawning every now and then.

Here's how the correct version of the function looks:

```
function addLinks(pattern:RegExp,text:String):String{
    var result = '';
    while(pattern.test(text)) result = text.replace(pattern, "<font color=\"#0000dd\"><a href=\"$&\">$&</a></font>");
    if(result == '') result+= text;//if there was nothing to replace
    return result;
}
```

As Cay mentioned, a stylesheet is more apropiate for styling.
Thanks for the input.

**UPDATE**

The RegEx listed above doesn't work when links contain the # sign.
Here's an updated version of the function:

```
function addAnchors(text:String):String{
    var result:String = '';
    var pattern:RegExp = /(?<!\S)(((f|ht){1}tp[s]?:\/\/|(?<!\S)www\.)[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/\/=]+)/g;
    while(pattern.test(text)) result = text.replace(pattern, "<font color=\"#0000dd\"><a href=\"$&\">$&</a></font>");
    if(result == '') result+= text;//if there was nothing to replace
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442245/c-replace-with-callback-function-like-in-as3) that in AS3 you have a replace function where you can pass a callback performing custom manipulation. This looks even more flexible than using standard regex capture groups.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to underline all the links in your textfield, the propper way to do it should be using [StyleSheet](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/text/StyleSheet.html)... try with something like this:

```
var style:StyleSheet = new StyleSheet();
style.setStyle("a", {textDecoration:"underline"});
tf.styleSheet=style;
tf.htmlText="hello <a href='#test'>world</a>";
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip. You are right about doing the propper thing, but what is more important than the underline is having the a href. In you example: "tf.htmlText="hello <a href='#test'>world</a>";" I want #test to be replaced with the pattern matched string (e.g. www.google.com, http://www.yahoo.com, stackoverflow.com, etc. )