# How to get value from match in ActionScript?

Tags: actionscript

How to get value from match in ActionScript?
What would an example be?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. What are you trying to match? What have you tried already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean a RegEx match, I know you can do that using the [replace()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/String.html#replace%28%29) method in the String class. All you need to do is use **$&**. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748569/how-do-i-replace-all-the-links-in-a-text-using-regex-in-as3) could be handy.

Otherwise, I don't know what you mean.