# how to replace all instances of a sub string in a string

Tags: regex, actionscript-3

I'm trying to work with RegEx to split a large string into smaller sections, and as part of this I'm trying to replace all instances of a substring in this larger string. I've been trying to use the replace function but this only replaces the first instance of the substring. How can I replace al instances of the substring within the larger string?

Thanks

Stephen

Answer (score 10, accepted):

adding `'g'` to searchExp. e.g. `/i_want_to_be_replaced/g`

Comment: dont forget, regexp is not within "". (i made that mistake)

Answer (score 3):

One fast way is use split and join:

```
function quickReplace(source:String, oldString:String, newString:String):String
{
    return source.split(oldString).join(newString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Alex's answer, you might also find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748569/how-do-i-replace-all-the-links-in-a-text-using-regex-in-as3) handy,
using String's [replace()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/String.html#replace%28%29) method.

here's a snippet:

```
function addLinks(pattern:RegExp,text:String):String{
    var result = '';
    while(pattern.test(text)) result = text.replace(pattern, "<font color=\"#0000dd\"><a href=\"$&\">$&</a></font>");
    if(result == '') result+= text;//if there was nothing to replace
    return result;
}
```